# Loading WCF config (for server + client) from custom source (not standard XML)

Tags: wcf, configuration

I've been trying to find a way to load my WCF service configuration (that huge BLOB of XML config data) from an alternate source - not the standard web.config / app.config.

We're running in a restricted environment where we don't have access to the server's file system, and thus we cannot make tweaks and changes to our WCF configs ourselves - we always have to find IT managers to handle that. We've put our entire configuration into a sQL Server database and trimmed down the web.config basically to a  section - that's it.

Now, we were wondering if there's a nice, documented way to do the same for WCF - is there a mechanism to plug in a "config provider" of sorts? Could we somehow store our config entries in a database table and feed them to the services as they start up?

I haven't been able to find any really useful and understandable documentation and samples on this..... any takers here?!?!

Comment: So you basically want to be able to configure your endpoints and behaviors via edits to the configuration that would be dynamically loaded when a request comes in? I guess you want to be able to change them via some sort of user interface which allows edits to this stored configuration?

Comment: Well, not even really dynamically - I would just like to store the whole WCF config that a service uses when starting up, or that a client uses when finding out how to connect to a service, somewhere else than the usual default XML config files. Things like binding, address etc.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this, it's a little bit of work though.

On the service side, You'll have to create your own custom [`ServiceHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) and override the [`ApplyConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.applyconfiguration.aspx) method.

Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/22/custom-service-config-file-for-a-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis.aspx)

On the client side, you do something similar, but provide a custom [`ChannelFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channelfactory.aspx) and override the [`ApplyConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channelfactory.applyconfiguration.aspx) method there.

Comment: Very interesting indeed - thank you very much for the pointer!