# How to parse a binding configuration from a config file?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, app-config

Normally, one can specify a service binding using the app.config file, and the system will automatically read from there. But what if my program is only a library (non-executable dll)? It can't have an app.config, and I can't change the main app code or config file. I can specify service binding using code, but this is not a good idea because I don't want to have to recompile each time binding changes.

My idea is having the complete  tag in a text file, my dll will read it and parse it to an WSHttpBinding object, and my code will use this object to create the service client.

How do I do the parsing?

Comment: There has to be a process that calls your class library. That application's config file is where you'd put your configuration settings. The host application will load the configuration and will make those available to your class library as if they were in it's own app.config file.

Comment: yeah.. problem is I'm not supposed to modify that main application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the source code in this forum post

- [Config Hosting multiple WCF services in one NT service](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f33e620a-e332-4fd4-ae21-88c750437355/)

Answer (score 1):

I think, this posts are related:

- [How can I specify an alternate config file for a WCF client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598632/)
- [Loading WCF config (for server + client) from custom source (not standard XML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312604/)